# How to save Multiple form on one request in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying save multiple form in multiple `child Component` from `parent Component` on one Request API.

I tried using `Context` and `reducer`.
It worked, but I'm wondering that whether the way is best?

My project like that:

```
import React from 'react'

const MasterForm = () => {
    const saveAll = () => {
        CallAPI();
    }

    return(
        <>
            <button onClick={saveAll} />
            <FormOfTable1/>
            <FormOfTable2/>
        </>
    )
}
```

Any solutions or advice for me?
Thank you!

Comment: Can you show code of `CallAPI()` function ?

Comment: Code above just frame in my head. 
The code i'm using `Context` is so complex,heavy and slow.

Answer (score 0):

Get the values from state and build data from the inputs. for example.

```
state = {
  name: '',
  address: '',
}
```

In your form add event handlers for your inputs

```
 <form>
  <label>
    Name:
    <input value={this.state.name} onChange={this.handleChange} type="text" name="name" />
  </label>
</form>

<form>
  <label>
    Address:
    <input value={this.state.address} onChange={this.handleChange} type="text" name="address" />
  </label>
</form>

<button onClick={this.saveAll}>Submit</button>
```

get the values from state for both forms, and send the data using [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) or [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)

```
saveAll = () => {

  // build data from both forms
  const { name, address } = this.state;

  axios.post(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users`, { 
    name,
    address
  })
    .then(res => {
      console.log(res);
      console.log(res.data);
  });

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.21.1/babel.min.js"></script>
        <div id="root"></div>

<script type="text/babel">

class App extends React.Component {

  state = {
    name: '',
    address: '',
  }

  saveAll = (e) => {

    e.preventDefault();

    // build data from both forms
    const { name, address } = this.state;

    console.log('name: ',name, '|| address: ', address);
    // axios.post(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users`, {
    //   name,
    //   address
    // })
    //   .then(res => {
    //     console.log(res);
    //     console.log(res.data);
    //   });

  }

  handleChange = (e) => {

    this.setState({
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    });

  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      <h3>form 1</h3>
        <form>
          <label>
            Name:
        <input value={this.state.name} onChange={this.handleChange} type="text" name="name" />
          </label>
        </form>
        <h3>form 2</h3>
        <form>
          <label>
            Address:
        <input value={this.state.address} onChange={this.handleChange} type="text" name="address" />
          </label>
        </form>

        <button onClick={this.saveAll}>Submit</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I started using [Formik](https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/) to solve that issue.

The thing to do is in your `MasterForm` component there needs to be a `state` which is passed on to the sub-forms. The sub-forms `<FormOfTable1/>` and `<FormOfTable2/>` needs to update that state. Since props are read only you cannot update it without a workaround.

You can check out an example of a multistep form [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/62nk7x0p73)